# zipcode distance range formula. Which formula is correct?

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, haversine

I need to find all the zipcodes with a certain range from a zipcode.  I have all the zipcode lat/lon in a DB.

I have found two formulas online that vary slightly from each other.  Which one is correct?

Formula 1:

```
def latRange = range/69.172
def lonRange = Math.abs(range/(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(zip.latitude)) * 69.172));
def minLat = zip.latitude - latRange
def maxLat = zip.latitude + latRange
def minLon = zip.longitude - lonRange
def maxLon = zip.longitude + lonRange
```

Formula 2: (is identical to formula one except for the following:)

```
def lonRange = Math.abs(range/(Math.cos(zip.latitude) * 69.172));
```

(The second one does not have `Math.toRadians` )
After I get the min/max Lat/Lon, I intend to search a DB table using a between criteria.  **Which formula is correct?**

Comment: You should Google for "Haversine forumula".  At best, your code above is determining something rectangle-ish, and I think you want to determine zipcodes that are within a circle about your center point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the units of your lat/long.  If they are in degrees, you need to convert to radians.

Comment: I dont think the data is in radians. I got it here: http://www.micahcarrick.com/php-zip-code-range-and-distance-calculation.html

Comment: @Tihom - should be easy to tell.  If you have any values over Pi, it's in degrees.

Answer (score 0):

If your  latitude and longitude data isn't already in radians then you'll need to use the one that converts.  You should be aware though that the way things are set up now you'll end up with a **square** range.

You'll be better off doing the distance calculation in your mysql query, using the Pythagorean theorem to find the distance so you end up with a **circular** range.
This question should help you get started with that: [mySQL select zipcodes within x km/miles within range of y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011944/mysql-select-query-based-on-lat-long-data-from-zipcode) .

If you need to improve it's performance you can index it using [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest letting the db do all the heavy lifting. Several DBs have geo add-ons, but here are a couple examples: [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing), [postgres+postgis](http://unserializableone.blogspot.com/2007/02/using-postgis-to-find-points-of.html)